# How to access Parent List Editform.aspx from child list NewForm.aspx form in SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, sharepoint

How to open **Parent List Item** Editform.aspx from **child list Item** NewForm.aspx form using a link in SharePoint 2013,For example if I am on child A NewForm.aspx I want to open parent A Editform.aspx,and for the rest of the child item to parent item

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a simple trick.
1) Goto to the parent list whose new form should open. 
2) copy the url of new form.aspx
3) goto child list open the list view page in SharePoint designer, edit the tag for new form url and replace the url with you have copied.
4) save and publish.
It should work.